# How to use a Bluetooth output sound while there is a Digital TV receiver connected to the phone jack?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, headphone-jack

I cannot find a way to get this to work properly. I want to connect my Android phone with Digital TV to my car's Bluetooth receiver. The TV's signal is boosted with an antenna connected to the phone jack of my cellphone. But when I connect the antenna the audio outputs directly from the phone itself and not from the Bluetooth. Is there a way to fix this?